# Can Ant expand environment variables from a properties file?

Tags: ant

I have a question regarding Ant and its treatment of environment variables.
To illustrate I have a small sample.

Given the Ant build file test.xml:

```
<project name="myproj" default="testProps">

    <property environment="env"/>

    <target name="testProps">
            <echo message="${env.MyEnvVar}"/>
            <echo message="${MY_PROPERTY}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

And the properties file test.props:

```
MY_PROPERTY=${env.MyEnvVar}
```

Now set the environment variable `MyEnvVar` to some value (foo in my case) and run Ant using this command line:

```
ant -f test.xml -propertyfile test.props testProps
```

The output I get is:

```
[echo] foo
[echo] ${env.MyEnvVar}
```

What I would like to know is whether there is any way to structure the input properties file such that I get

```
[echo] foo
[echo] foo
```

That is, I would like to name an environment variable in the properties file which is replaced within the Ant script.  Note - I know how to access environment variables directly (as is done here).  What I need to do is make use of a set of Ant scripts that expect one collection of properties in an environment that defines the same properties using different names.  Thus the thought of "bridging" them in a properties file.

I am using Ant version 1.6.5.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to read the `test.props` property file *after* the environment - you could do so using another `property` task, i.e. add

```
<property file="test.props" />
```

after your existing `property environment` task.

In full:

```
<property environment="env" />
<property file="test.props" />

<target name="testProps">
    <echo message="${env.MyEnvVar}"/>
    <echo message="${MY_PROPERTY}"/>
</target>
```

When you supply the properties file on the command line this gets processed before the content of the build, but at that time `${env.MyEnvVar}` is not yet set.

Comment: Not exactly what I hoping for, but it does work.  Have to see if I can make this work.  Thanks for the info.