# Ant: Unable to process environment variables set and working directoy

Tags: ant

I need to set some 10 environment variables before my CMAKE can run. This is what I am doing

Top of my build.xml has the following

```
<property environment="env" />
```

1. Creating a batch file with all the environment variables. I have something like this in my ANT Build.xml

       Calling runCompile

[image: step 1]

2. I then try to call CMAKE 
   [image: step 2]

Problems i am facing are:

1. I am unable to get any of the environment variables ex: when i try to print `${env.CMAKE_COMMAND}` it prints `${env.CMAKE_COMMAND}` and not value
2. When i try to goto working directory and execute the batch file, this also does not work.

Any idea how I can achieve the above?

Sorry I am unable to paste the XML code here. Hence attached as image.

Comment: I think the problem with your code formatting is that the code blocks are inside lists - try indenting them _twice_, i.e. 8 spaces instead of 4. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task documentation you will find a hint about the nested element [env](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html#env). With this it should be possible to *specify environment variables to pass to the system command*, like shown in the example:

```
<exec executable="emacs">
  <env key="DISPLAY" value=":1.0"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. i still get `${env.CMAKE_COMMAND}` printed :-(

Comment: @Karthik K  I suppose that setting the environment variable in the nested _env_ element will not affect the usage outside the executed executable. Maybe you should consider another approach like setting your environment with a property file like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241274/can-ant-expand-environment-variables-from-a-properties-file/3241484#3241484). You should be able to refer to them like `${CMAKE_COMMAND}`.